# What to name an array of flags?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, classname, bitflags

I have a project where lots of the objects hold state by maintaining simple boolean flags.  There are lots of these, so I maintain them within a `uint32_t` and use bit masking.  There are now so many flags to keep track of, I've created an abstraction for them (just a class wrapping the `uint32_t`) with `set()`, `clear()`, etc.

My question: What's a nice accurate, concise name for this class?  What name could I give this class so that you'd have a reasonable idea what it was [for] knowing the name only?

Some ideas I had:

- FlagBank
- FlagArray
- etc

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers,
-Chris

Comment: As a non-serious answer: I like FlagPole :-)

Comment: Are those flags managed by only one class ? if so <ClassName>Flags sounds appropriate.

Comment: Leave it to the C++ purists to favor the abstraction of individual bit twiddling ;-)

Comment: @nos: Unfortunately no, I'm using this throughout the codebase.  Otherwise, I'd just package a uintN_t or a bitset<N> in that class and code the accessors right in there with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlagBank would be fairly descriptive.

But I have one suggestion.  Instead of using uint32_t and bit masking, it might be less C-like to use an STL vector instead.  It uses a template specialization for the boolean case where only one bit per element is used for the storage.  Very efficient and MUCH more object oriented.

Comment: +1, but "less C-like" is not really a good reason IMHO. That's just incidental. `vector<bool>` (or even better, `bitset<N>`) is better just because it's easier to work with -- instead of writing `flags &= ~(1 << 4)` to turn off flag #5, you can write `flags[4] = false`.

Answer (score 10):

The Standard has such a class template and it is called `std::bitset<N>` (N for the number of bits/flags). The actual object of this class could be named according its purpose then, like `state` or something.